# flutter upgrader error - PlayStoreSearchAPI.lookupById returns null

Tags: flutter, compiler-errors, crashlytics

Every time I start the application I get this error. Crashlytics error, app_update_controller.dart. How to fix?

Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.1, on macOS 13.5.2 22G91 darwin-arm64, locale ru-AE)
Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
Chrome - develop for the web
Android Studio (version 2023.1)
VS Code (version 1.87.0)
Connected device (3 available)
Network resources

[image][image]

This is AppUpdateController, app_update_controller.dart:

```
    class AppUpdateController extends GetxController {
      final _logger = Get.find<ILogger>();
      String installedVersion = '';
      String packageName = '';
      String appName = '';
      String storeVersion = '';
      String itunesStoreUrl = '';
      final PlayStoreSearchAPI _playStoreSearchAPI = PlayStoreSearchAPI();
      final ITunesSearchAPI _iTunesSearchAPI = ITunesSearchAPI();
      late final FirebaseRemoteConfig remoteConfig;
      static const Duration remindLaterDuration = Duration(days: 1);
    
      static AppUpdateController get find => Get.find();
    
      Future<void> init(FirebaseRemoteConfig remoteConfig) async {
        this.remoteConfig = remoteConfig;
        await _checkAppUpdate(true);
      }
    
      void getPackageInfo() => _getPackageInfo();
    
      Future<void> _getPackageInfo() async {
        _logger.verbose('Getting package info...');
        var packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
        installedVersion = packageInfo.version;
        packageName = packageInfo.packageName;
        appName = packageInfo.appName;
      }
    
      Future<void> _checkAppUpdate(bool showAlert) async {
        await _getPackageInfo();
    
        if (Platform.isAndroid) {
          final response = await _playStoreSearchAPI.lookupById(
            packageName,
            country: Get.deviceLocale?.countryCode,
            language: Get.deviceLocale?.languageCode,
          );
          if (response == null) {
            _logger.error('Cant fetch android store version info');
            return;
          }
          final String? version = _playStoreSearchAPI.version(response);
          if (version == null) {
            _logger.error('Failed to parse android store version');
            return;
          }
          storeVersion = version;
        } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
          final response = await _iTunesSearchAPI.lookupByBundleId(packageName,
              country: Get.deviceLocale?.countryCode);
          if (response == null) {
            _logger.error('Cant fetch ios store version info');
            return;
          }
          final String? version = _iTunesSearchAPI.version(response);
          if (version == null) {
            _logger.error('Failed to parse ios store version');
            return;
          }
          storeVersion = version;
          itunesStoreUrl = _iTunesSearchAPI.trackViewUrl(response) ?? '';
        } else {
          _logger
              .info('Updater: Platform ${Platform.operatingSystem} not supported.');
          return;
        }
    
        final Version parsedCurrentVersion = Version.parse(installedVersion);
        final Version parsedStoreVersion = Version.parse(storeVersion);
    
        _logger.info(
            'Got version info from store. storeVersion: $parsedStoreVersion, currentVersion: $parsedCurrentVersion');
        if (parsedStoreVersion > parsedCurrentVersion) {
          _logger.info('Store version is newer. Requesting update...');
          final String minVersion =
              remoteConfig.getString(Defaults.remoteConfigMinVersionKey);
          final Version parsedMinVersion =
              minVersion.isEmpty ? Version(0, 0, 0) : Version.parse(minVersion);
          late final bool updateRequired;
          if (parsedMinVersion > parsedCurrentVersion) {
            updateRequired = true;
          } else {
            updateRequired = false;
          }
          final DateTime lastUpdateRequestedString =
              await _getLastUpdateRequestTime();
          final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
          if (!updateRequired &&
              now.difference(lastUpdateRequestedString).inSeconds <
                  remindLaterDuration.inSeconds) {
            _logger.info(
                'User suspended update by pressing "install later" button before');
            return;
          }
          RouteManagement.goToAppUpdateView();
        }
      }
    
      Future<DateTime> _getLastUpdateRequestTime() async {
        final String? lastUpdateRequestedString = await HiveService.get<String>(
            HiveBoxNames.lashUpdateRequested, Defaults.lastUpdateRequestedTimeKey);
        if (lastUpdateRequestedString == null) return DateTime(0);
        return DateTime.parse(lastUpdateRequestedString);
      }
    
      Future<void> _setLastUpdateRequestTime(DateTime date) {
        return HiveService.put(HiveBoxNames.lashUpdateRequested,
            Defaults.lastUpdateRequestedTimeKey, date.toIso8601String());
      }
    
      sendLaterLogs() {
        _logger.info('User pressed later update');
      }
    
      sendUpdateLogs() {
        _logger.info('User pressed update');
      }
    
      openStore() {
        if (Platform.isAndroid || Platform.isIOS) {
          final url = Uri.parse(
            Platform.isAndroid
                ? AppUrls.appPackageAndroidUrlFormat + packageName
                : itunesStoreUrl,
          );
          launchUrl(
            url,
            mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication,
          );
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: please share more info and the relevant code from app_update_controller.dart

Answer (score 0):

Your app throws an error message "Cant fetch android store version info".
from your code, it's happening when `_playStoreSearchAPI.lookupById` response is `null`.
assuming you're using the 'upgrader' package, if we check the [source code](https://github.com/larryaasen/upgrader/blob/master/lib/src/play_store_search_api.dart#L23) of this function we can see it can happen when the package's `id` is empty or cannot be found in the Play Store.

just replace this line

```
_logger.error('Cant fetch android store version info');
```

with

```
_logger.info('Cant fetch android store version info');
```

you could also replace all the
`_logger.error()` lines with `_logger.info()`, so that `_checkAppUpdate` function won't throw an error and just exit.

Comment: so how to solve this problem?

Comment: thank you ) I have one more question for you. Can you tell me why the Crashlytics logs are grouped incorrectly? What could be the reason?